# Why with django-postman that's doesn't work with this -> url(r'^messages/', include('postman.urls', namespace='postman', app_name='postman')),

Tags: python, django

I'm new with django, I would like use django-postman, and when I put : url(r'^messages/', include('postman.urls', namespace='postman', app_name='postman')), I have this error, idk why ? NameError: name 'url' is not defined
Why is it not defined ?
Just for test I replace url by path but that's doesn't work, I tried to install django postman in the terminal with pip, but that's doesn't work too.I really would like  have a solution for a messaging system between users for my project.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `re_path` instead of `url`.

Instead of this:

```
url(r'^messages/', include('postman.urls', namespace='postman', app_name='postman')),
```

Try this:

```
re_path(r'^messages/', include('postman.urls', namespace='postman', app_name='postman')),
```

Note: don't forget to import `re_path`

Comment: If it is helped you please accept the answer